# How can I create a SSH tunnel in a docker container where the socks proxy is accessible by the host machine?

Tags: docker, ssh

I want to use a docker container to create the ssh tunnel since there are issues compiling Obfuscated OpenSSH on Mac where as it is simple on Ubuntu.

Here is the docker file I'm using

```
FROM rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:zinglau/obfuscated-openssh
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN apt-get update
ADD ./Key.pem /var/www/
CMD ["ping", "google.com","-c 3"]

ENTRYPOINT ssh -z -Z obfuscatedkey -4 -i "/var/www/Key.pem" -N -p 53 -D 6969 ubuntu@REMOTE_SERVER_ON_AWS -v

EXPOSE 6969
```

The problem I'm getting is that it seems to connect but I can't connect to the SOCKS proxy on my host machine by  using 127.0.0.1:6969 as the proxy.

I've tried running it as `docker run -i -t NAME -p 127.0.0.1:6969:6969` and also `docker run -i -t NAME -P`

But the ssh tunnel freezes upon this step

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to REMOTE_SERVER_ON_AWS ([IP_ADDRESS]:53).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:6969 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 6969.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: can you explain what does `-D` do? I have used `-R` and `-L` and not sure I got `-D` usage correctly

Comment: I assumed it does similar thing to L but just more basic. When I use -D on my host computer normally (not connecting to the Obfuscated OpenSSH server just a normal one) I can use -D [PORT] to tunnel my traffic through it. So I would use -D then set my proxy as a socks proxy to 127.0.0.1:[PORT].

Comment: If you have an implementation that may work using -L let me know that may be useful. @TarunLalwani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a localhost tunnel inside the container. To use that tunnel you need to be inside the docker container.

When you use `-p 127.0.0.1:6969:6969` in docker run command. It says that port `6969` from the container will receive all traffic from your machine. But the container would receive the same from the IP assigned to the docker container. Which would be something like `172.2.0.2`.

You ssh tunnel inside the container is only listening to `127.0.0.1` and not `172.2.0.2`, so it will receive no such traffic. So change your Dockefile line

```
ENTRYPOINT ssh -z -Z obfuscatedkey -4 -i "/var/www/Key.pem" -N -p 53 -D 6969 ubuntu@REMOTE_SERVER_ON_AWS -v
```

to

```
ENTRYPOINT ssh -z -Z obfuscatedkey -4 -i "/var/www/Key.pem" -N -p 53 -D 0.0.0.0:6969 ubuntu@REMOTE_SERVER_ON_AWS -v
```

And if the `-D` option doesn't work the use `-L` option